# Test Solrnet resulting query url in Solr Admin

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am very new to SolrNet. So, I am not exactly sure how to test my queries in the Solr Admin tool. When I say Solr Admin tool I am referring to the web page UI that is used for testing queries, swapping cores, etc. I am trying to match my results in the Solr Admin with the results from my SolrNet query. The final generated query in my SolerNet application contains:

`q=("Crystal"~4)(*Crystal*)&start=0&rows=24&fq=department:(eyeglasses)&fq=status:(active)&fq=brand_site_code:(CS)&facet=true&facet.field=gender&facet.field=department&facet.field=color&facet.field=frame_shape&facet.field=frame_material&facet.field=face_shape&facet.limit=-1&indent=on&bq=name:(Sullivan)&sort=has_images+desc%2cseller_rank+asc%2cin_stock+desc%2cbrand_rank+asc%2cname+desc&version=2.2&wt=xml`

I am expecting the parameter `bq=name:(Sullivan)` to boost the name field to the top of the query if it is equal to "Sullivan". Is this URL valid? How could I test it in the Solr Admin?

Comment: The first thing you can do to find out why items are being scored as they are, is to append `debug=all` to your query and make the request directly to the core/collection (i.e. `/solr/collection/select?....`). That'll include information about exactly how the score for each document is calculcated and how much the `name:` boost contributes (boosts are not absolute, so you might want to weigh it more heavily by appending `^10` (or a higher weight).

Comment: That's very useful, thank you! I didn't think about just pasting the url into the browser. Now I can possibly mess with the query settings to figure this out.

Comment: The admin interface is just a small javascript layer on top of that endpoint anyway, and you'll have access to all the parameters (and not just those exposed in the interface) through the direct URL.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just figured out that my results were wacked because I was applying ```sort=has_images+desc%2cseller_rank+asc%2cin_stock+desc%2cbrand_rank+asc%2cname+desc``` and ```bq=name:(Sullivan)```. I can't boost and sort at the same time. The sort takes priority I am guessing.

Comment: That's correct. When you sort by a field, the score is irrelevant unless you include it as a sort parameter as well.